# Ruby on Rails build query in pieces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, chaining

There was a very similar question before but i still struggle. 
Is it possible to build a query up in stages?
Let's say I have a search form with many text and select fields that may be chained with and/or or which could be blank.
So the sql statement should consist of several parts that are connected individually for each search. 
I tried to create strings for every option and put them to a symbol? (i mean @options) and put that in the where clause (e.g. Product.where(@options) ). That works somehow but i have got troubles with this part: 'params[:query]' when it's in quotes. Either my sql statement says 'select products from products where (name like params[:query]')    or if i try #{params[:query]} it says: select products from products (where 'name' like ''.)

So how can i chain different parts of a query?

I looking forward to your answers!

Answer (score 8):

Never, *ever*, **ever** embed raw strings in your SQL. This is extremely bad form. You should always use the escaping mechanism provided by Rails or something equivalent to avoid ending up in serious trouble. Inserting content from `params` is very dangerous and should never be done as it only takes this to nuke your app: `{ :query => '\"-- DROP TABLE users;' }`

Generally you use the [helper methods](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where) provided by ActiveRecord to build up your query in stages:

```
scope = Product

if (params[:query].present?)
  scope = scope.where([ 'name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:query]}%" ])
end

if (params[:example].present?)
  scope = scope.where(:example => true)
end

@products = scope.all
```

You can build it up in stages like this, modifying the scope in-place each time, and then execute the final call to retrieve it. Generally that's when you use your paginator to split up the results.

It's okay to put pretty much anything in your options because it should be escaped by the time it hits the SQL phase, much as anything on the HTML side is escaped for you as well.

Don't confuse instance variables like `@options` with a symbol like `:query`. The two are very different things. Instance variables have the benefit of propagating to your view automatically, so they are often used extensively in controllers. Views should avoid modifying them whenever possible as a matter of style.

Comment: Well thank you so far, but how do i get "and" and "or" in my query? I mean sometimes i want that the query is: name like ? AND example like ? - and sometimes it should be: name like ? OR example like ? .

Comment: Why not just put it in that way? If you're chaining method calls you will get an `AND` automatically. To do an `OR` you will need to express it that way in the `where` clause.

Comment: To answer your comment: default is AND, so you can do `.where("1=1").where("name LIKE ?", '%whatever%')` (it will result in `WHERE 1=1 AND name LIKE '%whatever%'`). If you want OR in your query, you'll have to add it to single `where` call. Since you can have unlimited parameters on the where, you can do: `.where("name = ? OR other = ?", "first", "second")` ... or you can even do: `.where("name = :name OR other = :other", :name => "first", :other => "second")` (which will result in `WHERE name = 'first' OR other = 'second'`)

Comment: @tadman, when i try this. It starts executing the sql on each part. IN your example, it ends up firing 3 queries to the db, instead of one. Thats not what i would like. First you want to build the query and then execute once. Any idea?

Comment: It won't execute the query until you call `all` or another method which requires fetching data. @NoICE gives a more thorough example for both conditions that should work. The best thing to do if you are having problems with the implementation is to either update your question with more specifics or post a new question that can be answered.

Comment: @tadman, I'm running Rails 3.1 and MySQL 5.5. When i type: scope = Person and then scope = scope.where(:name => 'xyz') i see immediately a query fired on mysql (mysql log). Any idea?

Comment: Can you replicate in Rails 3.2? It could be a bug. `where` alone should only trigger a query with some other action called on it.

Comment: @tadman, i think i found it. It seems something todo with the console. When i run rails c, the queries are fired immediately. When running as server, the query works like you descriped.